# Inherit Base Page in User Control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

Below is my Code in Base Page

```
Public Class BasePage
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
```

Below is my Code in aspx page

```
Public Class ProposalEdit
Inherits BasePage
```

Below is my code in User Control

```
  Public Class CCTo
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

How can I inherit Base Page in UserControl. If I use BasePage in user control just like I used in aspx page, it is throwing the below error.

is not allowed here because it does not extend class **System.Web.UI.UserControl**.

Comment: A user control must inherit from `System.Web.UI.UserControl`... it can't inherit from `System.Web.UI.Page`... they're two different things.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @freefaller I am trying to access couple of properties from my Basepage

Comment: Can you make them public properties and access them via `CType(Me.Page, BasePage).MyProperty`?

Comment: @freefaller I google on what you said but unable to find the property. My properties are public

Comment: Without more details, there's not a lot I can do for you... I've shown you how to box the type of the page, if you can't see the property there is something else wrong